# How can i subscribe data with forkJoin in angular 10?

Tags: angular, typescript, subscribe

I am working on an angular project , i have one component where i should get data from different endpoints so i figured out that i can do that with forkJoin which was working but now nothing works even a simple console.log and i don't get any errors . This is my code:

```
 ngOnInit(): void {


 let summary = this.covidService.getSummary() ; 
 let lastDays=this.covidService.getSevenLastDays() ; 
 let getDataSince = this.covidService.getDataSince() ; 
 let getAllNews = this.covidService.getAllNews() ; 

 this.user = this.covidService.getUser() ;


  forkJoin(summary , lastDays , getDataSince , getAllNews).subscribe(([call1Response , call2Response 
   , call3Response , call4Response])=>{


  console.log("Hello world ") ; 

 
 }) ; 


}
```

Comment: Try investigating each of those streams separately: do `summary.subscribe(console.log, console.error, () => console.log('summary completed'))`, the same for `lastDays` etc.

Comment: Can you show more of your file? Are you importing forkJoin? Are the methods being called Observables? I can get it to print hello world on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-efypgg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method being used in the question is deprecated, so yes it would work for now, but could break in the future. The correct method is to pass an array of Observables or an Object of observables into the forkJoin.

I think you want to do it like this:

```
ngOnInit(): void {

    let summary = this.covidService.getSummary() ; 
    let lastDays=this.covidService.getSevenLastDays(); 
    let getDataSince = this.covidService.getDataSince(); 
    let getAllNews = this.covidService.getAllNews(); 

    this.user = this.covidService.getUser();


    forkJoin([summary , lastDays , getDataSince , getAllNews]).subscribe(response => {
        response.forEach(_response => console.log(_response);
    }); 
}
```

You could also do it like this:

```
ngOnInit() : void { 
    this.user = this.covidService.getUser();

    forkJoin({
        summary: this.covidSerivice.getSummary(),
        lastDays: this.covidService.getSevenLastDays(),
        getDataSince: this.covidService.getDataSince(),
        getAllNews: this.covidService.getAllNews()
    }).subscribe(response => {
        console.log(response.summary);
        console.log(response.lastDays);
        console.log(response.getDataSince);
        console.log(response.getAllNews);
    }
}
```

Comment: If the "Hello, world" doesn't show up in the console (so the original `forkJoin` doesn't emit), why would this do any better?

Comment: @mbojko I added some content to my answer on why to do it this way. I was able to get the method in the question working on stackblitz. That is also linked in a comment on the original question. I think we need to possibly see more on why theirs is not working?

Comment: Thank you very much this worked for me , thank you all .

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to see if it get any console error

```js
forkJoin(summary , lastDays , getDataSince , getAllNews).subscribe(
  function (x) {
    console.log('Next: %s', x);
  },
  function (err) {
    console.log('Error: %s', err);
  },
  function () {
    console.log('Completed');
  });
```